# Programmatically change selectedTemplate of CPTabBarTemplate

Tags: ios, swift, carplay

I'm trying to learn more about CarPlay. Specifically using `CPTabBarTemplate` (a new template as of 2020 and iOS 14).
What I'm looking to do is programmatically change the `selectedTemplate`, just as if I were updating a `selectedTab` in a `UITabBar`.
An example flow would be a `CPTabBarTemplate` with two tabs. A `CPPointOfInterestTemplate` and a `CPInformationTemplate`.

```
tabBarTemplate = CPTabBarTemplate(templates: [pointOfInterestTemplate, informationTemplate])
```

The user could select a point of interest and from the poi detail screen choose a button that might say "Select", just like in Apple's example from their [WWDC20 talk](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2020/10635/).
[image]

Upon pressing "Select", I want to programmatically take the user to the `informationTemplate` of the `tabBarTemplate` and then use the selected location's details to populate information in the `informationTemplate.`

I might not be understanding the way Apple expects `CPTabBarTemplate` to be used. There does exist a `selectedTab` property of `CPTabBarTemplate`. However, that property is `get` only. Which leads me to believe that the desired way to switch tabs is let the user tap the next tab themselves.

I'd be grateful for any insight. **If anyone knows how to programmatically update the selected tab of a `CPTabBarTemplate` that would be dandy.**

Thanks for reading!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think this is currently possible. The public interface of `CPTabBarTemplate` is very short but I couldn't even get it working by calling private api. Neither calling `tabTemplate.perform(Selector(("setIndexOfSelectedTab:")), with: 1)` nor the invoking function `tabTemplate.perform(Selector(("handleActionForControlIdentifier:")), with: tabTemplates[1].value(forKey: "identifier"))` made the trick (even though the tab bar delegate function is called with the correct selected template).

Comment: Turns out, you are correct. According to Apple `It is not currently possible to programmatically select a tab without user action.`
https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/681878

Answer (score 2):

I found a hacky solution for this case. Dirty code, but works for me:

```swift
root.updateTemplates([destinationTemplate])
DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 0.01) {
    root.updateTemplates(allTemplates)
}
```

The idea is to set your destination template as the only template. In this case the system automatically switches to it, as it is the only one. Then after a short delay you update your tab bar template to display all the templates. After doing it the system persists your selection.